# Does humankind know technique to transform uranium 238 to uranium 235, for nuclear plants?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Does humankind know technique to transform uranium 238 to uranium 235 ?
Is it using it for obtaining uranium 235 for nuclear plants ?
Or is it *selecting* uranium 235 from uranium ? Why not transform uranium 238 to 235 ? This would be more efficient, isn' it ?

Comment: sorry, I mean nuclear plant. ok, I fix it

Comment: A third option is to "use" U-235 while still in the original natural uranium isotope mix.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANDU_reactor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we can convert uranium-238 to uranium-235, but the last step of the conversion is a very slow process, so it's not practical. The standard way to obtain U-235 is to separate it out from natural uranium, typically using uranium hexafluoride; see [Enriched uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium) for descriptions of the various techniques.

Here are the steps to convert U-238 to U-235.

1. Irradiate U-238 with neutrons  to produce U-239, which has a half-life of about 23.45 minutes.
2. U-239 beta decays to neptunium-239, which has a half-life of about 2.356 days.
3. Np-239 beta decays to plutonium-239, which has a half-life of 24,110 years.
4. Pu-239 alpha decays to U-235.

Obviously, waiting 24,110 years is not practical. ;) But that's ok, because plutonium-239 is fissile, so it can be used as reactor fuel and in the production of fission weapons.

The above half-life data comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_uranium#Uranium-239 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-239

Comment: Thanks a lot PM 2Ring.

Comment: Substituting plutonium for uranium does lead to completely different design and engineering problems in both reactors and weapons...

Comment: @DJohnM That's certainly true, I didn't intend to imply that all fissile isotopes are equal. But that's a topic for another question, and questions about reactor design are possibly better suited to the engineering site.